# How to run a specific tasks once in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook that I am working on for a lab project that uses and EC2 instance to host a website. I am currently using Ubuntu as the OS. So by default when installing and enabling `apache2`, a default `index.html` file is stored in the `/var/www/html/` directory.

I wrote a task to delete the `index.html` file before pulling my source code for my website from my gitrepo. Everything works fine, but the problem is if I run this playbook again the delete `index.html` file will run and cause my website to go down.

So far my solution is to comment/delete the delete `index.html` task after the first run though on my playbook. Which is fine for now.

As a student, I want to learn any better methods to approach this issue. I tried using the `run_once`, but I cant seem to get it to actually run only once and never again.

Inventory file:

```ini
all:
  hosts:
    webserver:
      ansible_host: 
      ansible_user: 
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file:
    webserver02:
      ansible_host: 
      ansible_user: 
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: 
    webserver03:
      ansible_host: 
      ansible_user: 
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file:  

  children:
    webservers: 
      hosts: 
        webserver:
        webserver02:
        webserver03:
```

Playbook.yaml:

```yaml
- name: Install webserver packages
  hosts: webservers
  become: yes

  tasks:

    - name: Install apache2
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        name: "{{item}}"
        state: latest
        update_cache: yes
      loop:
        - apache2
        - git
        - zip
        - unzip

    - name: Start apache2 service
      ansible.builtin.service:
        name: apache2
        state: started
        enabled: yes

    ### Delete this tasks after running the playbook once ###

    - name: Remove default index.html
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /var/www/html/index.html
        state: absent

    - name: Clone the source code
      ansible.builtin.git:
        repo: "{{ gitrepo }}"    ### git source code ###
        dest: "{{ index_html }}" ### /var/www/html   ###
        single_branch: yes
        version: gottoweb
      notify: # the handler will only get executed if there is a change in the git task
        - restart apache2 service

  handlers: # this handler only restarts apache2 when there is a change in the git task
    - name: restart apache2 service
      ansible.builtin.service:
        name: apache2
        state: restarted
        enabled: yes
```

Tried different methods such as `run_once` and the `delegate_to` on the task in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *By default when installing and enabling `apache2`, a default `index.html` file is stored in the `/var/www/html/` directory. I wrote a task to delete the `index.html` file before pulling my source code for my website from my Git repository. Everything works fine, but the problem is if I run this playbook again the delete `index.html` file will run and cause my website to go down.*

I understand that you like to make your Ansible playbook [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency) and to only "delete" the default `index.html` but not your own project file.

Such kind of behavior can easily be achieved by a task like

```yaml
  - name: Backup once in preparation before overwrite
    copy:
      remote_src: true
      src: /var/www/html/index.html
      dest: /var/www/html/index.html.default
      force: false
```

It will create a copy of the default `index.html` on the Remote Node (`remote_src: true`) only if the task wasn't run before successfully (`force: false`). You can than just pull your source code for your website from your Git repository, containing the project `index.html` file. It will overwrite the left default `index.html` file with your version.

> *As a student, I want to learn any better methods to approach this issue.*

Simplifying this further, there might be no need to backup, move or delete the default configuration at all, just drop that task and let the `git` task overwrite the files.